# Microsoft Graph API call getOffice365ActiveUserDetail fails with HTTP 403

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, report

I try to call Microsoft Graph APIs reports call: [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period=%27D7%27))

But it fails with error HTTP 403. Is there a way exists to overcome this?

Comment: Outside of your application, can you repro the issue? Say, i would try with Microsoft Graph explorer.

Comment: I tried with Microsoft Graph explorer i can repro the issue with the same API call. Please keep in mind that HTTP 403 is forbidden error. It tells that you're not allowed or  dont have permission to call the API. Make sure you have necessary permissions provided.

Comment: I tried with MS Graph explorer, i can repro the issue. Then i tried updating the permission called "Reports.Read.all", with admin consent provided so i can read all the usage reports. Now, i tried with Graph explorer, boom, it works for me. Try the above and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes @Dev i can repro the issue with MS Graph explorer as well. Its throwing HTTP 403 error again. Sounds like issue with API?

Comment: No @Alice. I would still suggest you to look at my last reply, try the steps and see if you can repro the issue or not. Still if there is an issue, update here, so that i can see how best i can help you.

Comment: Will test it and update you by tomorrow. Thanks @Dev again for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks @Dev. I tested what you suggested and it worked for me!! Thanks one more time.

Comment: Great news @Alice. I will move to answer. Also i see that Chauncy updated related info below too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With Microsoft Graph explorer i can repro the issue with the same API call. HTTP 403 is forbidden error. It tells that you're not allowed or dont have permission to call the API. Make sure you have necessary permissions.
- Tried updating the permission "Reports.Read.all", with admin consent provided so i can read all the usage reports. Now, i tried with Graph explorer, and it works for me.
- You tested the same, confirmed it works for you.
- Here's the related [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activeuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)!!

Comment: Awesome @Dev for your assistance. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Dev said,please add the Delegated permisson or the Application permission below and test it again.
[image]