# MS Graph API call getOffice365ActiveUserDetail() fails with HTTP 403 for Delegated permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Earlier i asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793803/microsoft-graph-api-call-getoffice365activeuserdetail-fails-with-http-403/), where @Dev helped me. Now when i tried doing to Delegated permissions, its again throwing HTTP error 403. Application permission works for me. Only looks like issue with delegated permission. Strange? Any inputs will be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alice, I see that you're using delegated permission scenario. If yes, then you need to allow apps to read service usage reports on behalf of a user. I would suggest you to work with your tenant administrator. They should have assigned the user the appropriate Azure AD limited administrator role - its needed, apart from the permissions that you specify in your code.

I tried the above in past and helped; so give a try. If you still face issues let me know. For more info you can refer the [related document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/reportroot-authorization).

Comment: Thanks @Dev for your valuable inputs. I will work with my tenant administrator to see if it helps.

Comment: I worked with my tenant admin and the above documentation, steps helped us to fix the issue. Now its working. Thank you Microsoft Graph Guru @Dev!!

Comment: Glad to help @Alice!!